# Can I mask an ASP:textbox with Jquery by just referencing it in the ID?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have this:

```
<td>
 <asp:TextBox ID="datet" ToolTip="Formato dd/mm/aaaa" runat="server"> 
 </asp:TextBox>
</td>
```

and this

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
        $(function () {
            // only numbers are allowed
            $('#text_input_1').filter_input({ regex: '[0-9]' });
            $('#datet').mask("99/99/9999", { placeholder: "/" });
        });
    </script>
```

Is it possible to reference this function inside the ASP tag? I mean, I know it´s not possible by the way I did it.

Comment: I'm rusty on ASP.NET, but I think if you check the id of the HTML textbox on the rendered page, the id value will not be "datet". I think in your JS code you need do something like `$('#<%= datet.ClientID %>')`

Answer (score 0):

try as below:

```
$('[id$=datet]').mask("99/99/9999", { placeholder: "/" });
```

instead of

```
$('#datet').mask("99/99/9999", { placeholder: "/" });
```